# Best practice for ansible apt-key when considering cross-platform

Tags: ansible

I'm looking into making all my Ansible roles cross compatible, but I'm starting with Darwin (Mac OSX). I'm almost complete, but I've hit a stump I'm not entirely sure how to get around without the use of `command`, `shell`, `raw`, or unique tasks per distribution...

```
- name: "Ensure key is present"
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  apt_key:
    keyserver: "{{ role_keyserver }}"
    id: "{{ role_id }}"
    state: present
```

How would I make the above Ansible task compatible for Darwin without the use of `command`, `shell`, or `raw` tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you just put the actually cross platform tasks in your role's tasks/main.yml and then have a task that includes OS specific task lists at an appropriate point.

So a quick example might be to have something like this:

#### tasks/main.yml

```
- name: os specific vars
  include_vars: "{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}"

- name: os specific tasks
  include: "{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}.yml"

- name: enable service
  service:
    name: "{{ service_name }}"
    state: started
    enabled: true
```

And then you might have your OS specific files such as this:

#### vars/redhat

```
service_name: foobar
service_yum_package: "{{ service_name }}"
```

#### tasks/redhat.yml

```
- name: install service
  yum:
    name: "{{ service_yum_package }}"
```

#### vars/debian

```
service_name: foobaz
service_apt_package: "{{ service_name }}"
```

#### tasks/debian.yml

```
- name: install service
  apt:
    name: "{{ service_yum_package }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apt is only the package manager for Debian-based distributions, so you probably want to add [a when statement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) onto the end of that block:

```
- name: "Ensure key is present"
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  apt_key:
    keyserver: "{{ role_keyserver }}"
    id: "{{ role_id }}"
    state: present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

This will skip the task when run on a Darwin host.

If you have some similar task you need to run, but for Darwin, then you can similarly condition it on [a fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) so it only runs on Darwin hosts.